# bash retry function with silencer

Tags: bash, error-handling, stdout

I found a bash function, that let's me retry commands.

```
function retry {
  local n=1
  local max=50
  local delay=1
  while true; do
    "$@" && break || {
      if [[ $n -lt $max ]]; then
        ((n++))
        echo "[$n/$max] ($?) $@:" >&2
        sleep $delay;
      else
        fail "The command has failed after $n attempts."
      fi
    }
  done
}

function fail {
  echo $1 >&2
  exit 1
}
```

I use it like this

```
$ retry ping -q -c 1 $ip
```

However, when retrying commands, I never want to see the commands stderr or the stdout output. How can I silence the command when retrying like this?

Comment: What does the `fail` function do? (Presuming it's a function)

Comment: updated question to address comment

Comment: oh by the way, I realize that ping doesn't need to be wrapped in a retry command, because ping retries by default. but the retry function is handy in a variety of other situations

Comment: REdirecting the STDERR & STDOUT to `/dev/null`, no? `command_you_need > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to silence all output of *the command* executed by the `retry` function, change

```
"$@" && break || {
```

to:

```
"$@" &>/dev/null && break || {
```

in the script or simply give it along with the argument, e.g.:

```
retry "ping -q -c 1 $ip &>/dev/null"
```

---

If you however want to silence all output of *the whole function*, either comment out every `echo` line in your script and do the change explained above or append `&>/dev/null` on the command line, e.g.:

```
retry ping -q -c 1 $ip &>/dev/null
```

Comment: possible alternative

Comment: eval "$*" && break || {

Comment: retry "ping -q -c 1 $ip >/dev/null 2>/dev/null"

Comment: @joshsverns How is `>file 2>file` better than `&>file`?

Comment: Is your answer working on yours? because I'm getting './bin/functions: line 20: ping -q -c 1 52.91.115.97 &>/dev/null: No such file or directory' when trying option B

Comment: @joshsverns I can't test a script if you don't provide it. ;P If I just call the function with `retry $@` in the script it works very well for me (tested with `true` and `false`).

Comment: since true has no output or args, try
ping -q -c 1 8.8.8.8

Answer (score -1):

I do my testing on bsd/macos, this seems to work. The other answer didn't work. I'm guessing it would also work in my ubuntu production environment.

```
function retry {
  local n=1
  local max=50
  local delay=1
  echo contained "$@"
  while true; do
    eval "$*" &>/dev/null && break || {
      foo=$?
      if [[ $n -lt $max ]]; then
        ((n++))
        echo "[$n/$max] ($foo) $@" >&2
        sleep $delay;
      else
        fail "The command has failed after $n attempts."
      fi
    }
  done
}




retry "ping -q -c 1 $ip"
```